# Can QGIS display coordinates in a chosen format as I move the mouse over a topographical map?

Tags: qgis, wgs84, mapping

Australian bushwalkers offer map coordinates in the GDA94-56 format (essentially identical to WGS84). When I am working on topo maps in QGIS, it would be fantastic to quickly locate a coordinate within the map that is listed in this format (e.g. GDA462568).

Is QGIS capable of displaying coordinates continuously as the cursor moves?

If not, what is the most efficient way to input coordinates as waypoints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QGIS display the coordinate of your map cursor at the bottom (see n°1 on below picture), by clicking on the symbol next to it (n°2) you may alternate between coordinate display and extents display.

You have some control on how these information are displayed by accessing the General tab in the project properties window (go to "Project" > "Properties..." or click on n°3)

[image]

Also as it seem that GDA94-56 is a projected CRS you could open the Advanced Digitizing panel and toggle Floater (this only work in an edit session) that will display coordinate next to the Add feature tool cursor. this panel also let you to directly input coordinate.

[image]